# Forecasting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, forecasting

I am attempting to adapt some Excel formulas for forecasting to Google Sheets with limited success. Does anyone know the equivalent for these Excel formulas?

FORECAST.ETS
FORECAST.ETS.CONFINT

Thanks,